# Postgresql remove and add data to table

Tags: postgresql

I have 2 tables. Table A has a foreign key to Table B. Now Table B-s content is deleted and new content is added. New content is similar to the old one. How can i delete the content of Table B, add new content and then update the refrences in Table A.

Do i have to create a temporary table. Add the data. Then delete old foreign key. Now use some additional info to match old data id-swith new ones, create a new foregin key to the temp table. Delete the old table and place the temporary table in the place of the old table ?

Comment: delete and insert with same PK value?.. why not just `UPDATE`?..

Comment: Post sample data with the `create table` statements.